# How to animate background every 20 millisecond on Android Wear?

Tags: android, animation, sequence, wear-os

I'm searching for answers but I cannot find them :( I'm trying to build a watch face for android wear using only just a background animation (sequence of 20 jpegs or png's). I found this great example: https://github.com/btrax/sample-watch-face-official-api

In this example the author switches background image every 1 minute using this class.

```
private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
    float HOUR_HAND_LENGTH = 80.0f;
    final float MINUTE_HAND_LENGTH = 120.0f;
    final int[] BACKGROUND_RES_ID = {
            R.drawable.image_1,
            R.drawable.image_2,
            R.drawable.image_3,
            R.drawable.image_4,
    };
}
//...and then...

// draw background

        Resources resources = MyWatchFaceService.this.getResources();
        int imgResId;
        if (isInAmbientMode()) {
            imgResId = R.drawable.black_background;
        } else {
            imgResId = BACKGROUND_RES_ID[mTime.minute % BACKGROUND_RES_ID.length];
        }
```

I can change mTime.minute to mTime.second but this is not enough. I want to draw background images one after another without delay (milliseconds).

imgResId = BACKGROUND_RES_ID[mTime.second % BACKGROUND_RES_ID.length]

I cannot find any (code) example od watch face over internet which has animated (frame by frame) background.

Comment: put this line  invalidate() inside on OnDraw Method

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `invalidate()` for the watch face to redraw. In the example you are using, `invalidate()` is only called `onTimeTick()`, which happens once a minute. You want it to keep happening. If you want, you can use a handler that will fire once a second and call `invalidate()` or you can simply add this:

```
        /* Draw every frame as long as we're visible and in interactive mode. */
        if ((isVisible()) && (!mAmbient)) {
            invalidate();
        }
```

At the end of the `onDraw()` method.